# how to share same service instance between 2 lazy loaded modules - not at root

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-lazyloading

Is it possible to share the same instance for a service, between two lazy loaded modules, where that service is not provided at the root injector? Or at least, not provided until called upon?

E.g. I have `LazyModuleA` and `LazyModuleB` that are, as named, loaded lazily. Each of these modules need access to the same service, but that service is not needed anywhere else. The shared service should only have a single instance shared among the modules. Also, it should not be loaded or accessible outside those two modules.

Currently I'm providing the service in the root injector via `{providedIn: 'root'}` . Is it possible to load the same instance of this service for both of these lazy loaded modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting, I am not sure if this would work, I haven't tried myself, how about if you have a 3rd module, in it, there is your service without `providerIn: root`.

Your service:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MySharedService {
 // ... some code
}
```

This 3rd module:

```js
@NgModule({
   providers: [MySharedService],
   exports: [MySharedService] // I'm not sure if this is need it 
})
export class ModuleC {}
```

LazyModuleA:

```js
@NgModule({
   import: [ModuleC]
})
export class LazyModuleA {}
```

LazyModuleB:

```js
@NgModule({
   import: [ModuleC]
})
export class LazyModuleB {}
```

So your `LazyModuleA` and `LazyModuleB` both have imported ModuleC which is exporting your desired `service`.

Comment: Brilliant! Not sure where this service ends up in the injector tree, but it's the same instance being used in both modules now. Kind thanks to you.

Comment: Oh btw, do not export `MySharedService` from `ModuleC`.

Comment: It doesn't work, at least not in angualr 14, both lazy loaded modules end up with their own instances of service :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 lazy loaded services that you want to share instance of service, then you have to wrap them in another lazy module (lets call it LazyModuleC), and provide service in that module.

So lets say you have LazyModuleA, loaded for path '/pathA', and LazyModuleB, loaded for path '/pathB'.

Then you can create LazyModuleC to add routings for A and B, and provide service that you want to share between them:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'pathA',
    loadChildren: () => LazyModuleA
  }
  {
    path: 'pathB',
    loadChildren: () => LazyModuleB
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  providers: [ServiceInQuestion]
})
export class LazyModuleC {
}
```

Then you will need to laod LazyModuleC in your app routing, just add this to routes array:

```
{
  matcher: simpleMatcher,
  loadChildren: () => LazyModuleC 
}
```

While matcher can be something simple like this:

```
export function simpleMatcher(segments: UrlSegment[]): UrlMatchResult {
  if (segments.length > 0 &&
    (segments[0].toString() === 'pathA' || segments[0].toString() === 'pathB')) {
      return {
        consumed: [],
        posParams: null
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

With that you will have LazyModuleC, that will have its own injector, and will provide service that you want. And it will load LazyModuleA and LazyModuleB, and those modules will find service provider in LazyModuleC's injector. This way they will share the instance